# How can I plot two groups of raincloud plots on the same plot without overlap?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have multiple main groups of datasets, and each main group consists of three subgroups. I would like to vertically plot these three subgroups for each main group as a raincloud plot, with the main groups plotted on different x positions on the same plot. While I have successfully plotted the subgroups, when I attempt to plot them on different x positions, they overlap. How can I achieve this? Here is the code I have used for two main groups::

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ptitprince as pt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 12))
pal = sns.color_palette("tab10", 10)

pt.RainCloud(x='Group1', y='Value1', data=dx_1, bw=0.15, cut=0, orient='v', width_box=0.05,
             width_viol=0.25, palette = [pal[8]], ax=ax1)
pt.RainCloud(x='Group1', y='Value1', data=dx_2, bw=0.15, cut=0, orient='v', width_box=0.05,
             width_viol=0.25, palette = [pal[6]], ax=ax1)
pt.RainCloud(x='Group1', y='Value1', data=dx_3, bw=0.15, cut=0, orient='v', width_box=0.05,
             width_viol=0.25, palette = [pal[9]], ax=ax1)
pt.RainCloud(x='Group2', y='Value2', data=dx_1, bw=0.15, cut=0, orient='v', width_box=0.05,
             width_viol=0.25, palette = [pal[8]], ax=ax1)
pt.RainCloud(x='Group2', y='Value2', data=dx_2, bw=0.15, cut=0, orient='v', width_box=0.05,
             width_viol=0.25, palette = [pal[6]], ax=ax1)
pt.RainCloud(x='Group2', y='Value2', data=dx_3, bw=0.15, cut=0, orient='v', width_box=0.05,
             width_viol=0.25, palette = [pal[9]], ax=ax1)
```

and my datasets
dx_1:

```
Value1  Group1  Value2  Group2
0   -13     a     1     b
1   -10     a     2     b
2   -14     a     3     b
3   -12     a     4     b
4   -20     a     5     b
```

dx_2

```
Value1  Group1  Value2  Group2
0   -1      a     3     b
1   -1      a     4     b
2   -1      a     2     b
3   -1      a     4     b
4   -2      a     5     b
```

dx_3:

```
Value1  Group1  Value2  Group2
0   -10     a     1     b
1   -2      a     2     b
2    4      a     3     b
3   -1      a     4     b
4   -2      a     5     b
```

I would appreciate your help